# difference between data-open and data-toggle in Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

What is the difference between data-open and data-toggle in Foundation 6.2 when used for offcanvas? Why use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Data-toggle switches the state (open if closed, close if opened). Data-open will just open it.

Comment: Why use one over the other?